# Setting a custom text in the center ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Is it possible to add a custom text in the center of the Sherlock Action Bar?

I know we can set it on the right like when we add buttons, or next to the logo, but what about in the center of the bar?

EDIT:

I did this, and it renders, but it's just not centered in the bar.

```
LayoutInflater linflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(getApplicationContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
View GalleryTitleView = linflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_title_layout, null); 
GalleryTitleTv = (TextView) GalleryTitleView.findViewById(R.id.GalleryTitleTv); 
ActionBar.LayoutParams lp = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL; 
GalleryTitleView.setLayoutParams(lp); 
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(GalleryTitleView); 
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a custom view with `ActionBar.LayoutParams`'s `gravity` set to `Gravity.CENTER`.

Comment: Please have a look at the Updated Question

Answer (score 0):

Make Changes in the `Gallery_title_layout.xml` by setting textview's gravity in the `center|horizantal_Center`,
I suggest you to use the relative layout

Answer (score 0):

If you want the text completely centered in the Action Bar, in addition to having others actions & buttons; then you need to put the text (view) within a custom view.  In my experience, if you put the text within an action (view or provider), you cannot give it a layout parameter of MATCH_PARENT and expect it to take up the entire length of the Action Bar.

Here is a tutorial on how to put the custom view: https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/R49wVvcDoEW

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
View customView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.actionbar_title, null);
ActionBar.LayoutParams params = new ActionBar.LayoutParams(ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ActionBar.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, Gravity.CENTER);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP );
```